# How to set library searching path using environment variable in compile-time

Tags: compiling, gcc

-I option set header file searching path for **gcc/g++**, and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH/CPATH append the searching path list.

Then what about libs? It seems that **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is just a path list for  **run-time** library searching. -L option is necessary to specify any lib path other than /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib.

Is there an environment variable similar to CPATH/CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, to do the **compile-time** job?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used for the run-time search of dynamically linked libraries, as those are *dynamically* linked libraries. If you want something defined on compile time, have you considered statically-linked libraries? (You get this by passing the `-static` option to `gcc` or to the linker.)

Comment: There is nothing to worry about runtime execution. I just want to configure the compile environment in my .bashrc rather than gcc command line.

Comment: Oh, got it. From the manpage, I guess `LIBRARY_PATH` is what you're looking for, "The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, [...] Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first)."

Comment: Also, if you're going through your first steps in program compilation, be sure to read a bit about `Makefiles` and [`make`](http://enwp.org/Make%20(software)), which are one of the ways to automate the compile options and procedures for a project.

Comment: LIBRARY_PATH works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Q appears to have been answered in the comments. Per [njsg's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14831/njsg) [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42634/how-to-set-library-searching-path-using-environment-variable-in-compile-time#comment58530_42634),

> LIBRARY_PATH is what you're looking for
>
> "The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, [...] Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first)."